# golang FTP PASS (password) command works locally, but doesn't while running on ECS

Tags: go, ftp, amazon-ecs, eof, ftp-client

I have a go server that uses `github.com/jlaffaye/ftp` library for getting FTP files from a remote server.
I first of all get the connection

```
    conn, err := ftp.DialTimeout(cfg.Host+cfg.Port, time.Second*15)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("ftp dial error: %v", err)
    }
```

After which, I try to login with

```
    err = conn.Login(cfg.Username, pwd)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("ftp login error: %v", err)
    }
```

I log in successfully while running locally.
This is also confirmed while looking at the output of

```
        code, msg, err := c.cmd(StatusLoggedIn, "PASS %s", password)
        log.Printf("pass, code %d, msg %s, err %v", code, msg, err)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
```

Which is from my vendor pkg under `\vendor\github.com\jlaffaye\ftp\ftp.go`
With the output being

`2021/06/16 23:12:45 pass, code 230, msg User xxxx logged in, err <nil>`

While running the same service deployed on amazon ECS,
the output of the vendored pkg under `\vendor\github.com\jlaffaye\ftp\ftp.go` becomes

`2021/06/16 20:24:28 pass, code 0, msg , err EOF`

Can someone please recommend an idea on what might be causing this?

Comment: Also wanted to note that `err = conn.Login(cfg.Username, pwd)` runs the FTP USER command also. This step passes while running both locally and on ECS

Comment: using an `if errors.Is(err, io.EOF)` and returning `nil` if true helps, but later still get `EOF` while running other FTP commands.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the ftp server is not reachable when running from amazon ECS because the IP address for the ec2 machine isn’t whitelisted in the ftp server.
Did some debugging with `telnet`

From local machine behind our VPN

```
# telnet ftp.xxxxxxxxx.net 21
Trying xx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to xxxxxxxxxxx.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ProFTPD 1.3.5 Server (ProFTPD Default Installation) [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
USER xxxx
331 Password required for xxxx
PASS xxxxxxxxx
230 User xxx logged in
```

From an EC2 machine in a different VPC

```
Connected to ftp.xxxxxxxxxxxx.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ProFTPD 1.3.5 Server (ProFTPD Default Installation) [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
USER xxxx
331 Password required for xxxx
PASS xxxxxxxx
Connection closed by foreign host.
```